# Can't get good quality audio/video

Tags: apache-flex, flash-media-server

I'm creating a video chat application, and no matter what combination of Camera/Microphone/NetStream properties and functions I use, I cannot get high quality video/audio. I get occasional audio latency, pixelated video, occasional frozen video and the degree of each depends on the combination of properties/functions I set/call.

Others such as TokBox, TinyChat, Chat Roulette, etc. have achieved great video/audio quality with FMS, what is the secret? At least point me in the right direction, because right now I'm not impressed with FMS ability to provide a good video/audio experience.

BTW, I'm using a P2P mesh using a group specifier, not NetStream.DIRECT_CONNECTIONS.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try `Camera.setQuality` function (on the client), particularly the 'bandwidth' parameter.  You might also want to look at your own internet/server connection since by default the quality changes appropriately to the bandwidth.  Those other sites have server farms with *massive* amounts of bandwidth, something I doubt you have yourself.

Comment: I've tried Camera.setQuality() with various combinations of the bandwidth and quality parameters, but that did not solve the issue. Because in this case I am using P2P, and thus the video does not go through the server, I would think the server would matter. I believe those other products are also using P2P and not going through the server, correct?

Comment: not many as p2p isn't very reliable since it's based on the user's connection, and not your server's.  I haven't seen really good p2p video as of yet mostly because of bandwidth limitations.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RTMFP, You cannot depend on the quality as it is a peer-2-peer technology. If you need quality and recording stuff, go for RTMP.